# How do i type something into an input box with the puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm doing experiments for a bot im making but for some reason things i cant get it to type into the input box in youtube.

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/?hl=hr&gl=HR');

    await page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    });
    await page.type('#search', `text`)

    // await browser.waitForTarget(() => false)
    // await browser.close();
})();
```

The #search is the id for the youtube search bar but it isn't working for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is waitUntil: 'networkidle0'

```
async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/?hl=hr&gl=HR');
  await page.waitForSelector('input#search')
  await page.type('input#search', `text`)
})();
```

Comment: This works. thank you for helping e though i do have one question, why is "input" in ```input#search``` needed? I tried wait for selector before but it didn't work so it seems as though adding input fixed it. Can you please explain as to why this is?

Comment: If you type "document.querySelectorAll('#search')" in the devtools console you can see that there are actually 3 elements with the #search id

Comment: SO input specifies that it is an input? Thanks.